# anaconda/spyder scikit learn update 0.21.3 to 0.22.2

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda, conda

anaconda/spyder scikit learn  update 0.21.3 to 0.22.2

```
(base) mm@mm:~$ python --version
Python 3.7.4
(base) mm@mm:~$ anaconda --version
anaconda Command line client (version 1.7.2)
```

My `scikit-learn` version is 0.21.3 but I can't update to 0.22.2 
I have tried multpile ways to update  but I think this version is not included in my channels. I am using the default channels

How can I update `sckit-learn` using `conda` or any other possible way

my history (commands I have tried):

```
 1509  conda update conda
 1510  spyder 
 1511  conda list
 1512  conda update scikit-learn
 1513  anaconda
 1514  navigator-updater 
 1515  conda list scikit-learn
 1516  conda install scikit-learn=0.22.2
 1517  conda install scikit-learn=0.22
 1518  conda install scikit-learn==0.22.2
 1519  conda install -c intel scikit-learn
 1520  spyder 
 1521  history
```

And the error I get when trying to `conda install`:

```
(base) mm@mm:~$ conda install scikit-learn=0.22.2
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - scikit-learn=0.22.2

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
```

Comment: What error does `conda install scikit-learn=0.22` give you? `conda search scikit-learn` will show no 0.22.2 version available, but 0.22 and 0.22.1 is available.

Comment: **Don’t use the base environment for development!** There’s rarely any reason to even touch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every package and not always the most recent versions of packages are available from the default channels when using `conda install`.

There are two ways you can check what is available from your configured channels:

`conda search scikit-learn` gives you a list of all packages that match the name `scikit-learn` and the available versions. On linux x64, this gives me this:

```
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel
<shortened to last few lines of list>
scikit-learn                  0.22.1  py36h22eb022_0  pkgs/main
scikit-learn                  0.22.1  py36hd81dba3_0  pkgs/main
scikit-learn                  0.22.1  py37h22eb022_0  pkgs/main
scikit-learn                  0.22.1  py37hd81dba3_0  pkgs/main
scikit-learn                  0.22.1  py38h22eb022_0  pkgs/main
scikit-learn                  0.22.1  py38hd81dba3_0  pkgs/main
```

So only `0.22.1` is available from the default channels. You can also check using [anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org/search?q=scikit-learn) where you can use the saerch function to get this:
[image]

Note the small gray numbers that indicate that `anaconda / scikit-learn` (the mirror of the default channel) only has version `0.22.1`, in accordance with `conda search output`.

Note also that `conda-forge / scikit-learn` has your desired version, so you can use this command to install:

```
conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn=0.22.2
```